# Event handler scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is probably an easy question but I can't figure out the best answer for it.

I have 10 `<div>` elements on screen. Each of them has a `click()` event listener:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="element0">Click me! (0)</div>
    <div id="element1">Click me! (1)</div>
    <div id="element2">Click me! (2)</div>
    <div id="element3">Click me! (3)</div>
    <div id="element4">Click me! (4)</div>
    <div id="element5">Click me! (5)</div>
    <div id="element6">Click me! (6)</div>
    <div id="element7">Click me! (7)</div>
    <div id="element8">Click me! (8)</div>
    <div id="element9">Click me! (9)</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        var element = document.getElementById( "element" + i );
        element.onclick = function () {
            alert( "Element " + i );
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But every time I click on an element it says "Element 10"! It seems all those event handlers are using the same value for `i`.

I want it to show "Element N" where N is the number of the current element. I don't want to extract N from the element id. Neither I want to store it using `data()` method of jQuery. I believe there must be a much simpler solution to this problem, but I can't find it. Anyone?

Comment: `i` is declared in the global scope and not within the `onclick` function, therefore it is being read from the global scope when accessed within the `onclick`. It shows `10` because that was the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have one variable `i` in an outer scope shared by all your click handlers.  You need to create a local variable `i` for each closure. This will work:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( "element" + i );
    element.onclick = (function(i){
        // returns a new function to be used as an onclick handler
        return function () {
            alert( "Element " + i );
        }
    })(i); // Pass in the value of the outer scope i
}
```

Check "The Infamous Loop" problem in [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) (and read the whole artice) for more information :)

Comment: so I'm creating two functions for every event listener. Isn't there a more efficient and cleaner version?

Comment: @AlexStack This is pretty efficient. You have an anonymous function in your loop, which executes immediately and returns a new function with a local i variable for each click handler. Each event handler is still only one function.

Comment: I know, but in our project there will be thousands of this function created every few seconds. That's why I'm concerned about efficiency.

Comment: @AlexStack I don't think that will be an issue. I'm getting consistently under 700 milliseconds to generate 10000 divs with that onclick handler and a mouseover and a mouseout handler plus some styles: http://jsfiddle.net/GVxSk/2/

Comment: @AlexStack Of course Jamund's event delegation solution is about twice as fast giving me under 350 milliseconds consistently: http://jsfiddle.net/GVxSk/3/

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is the nature of doing async code inside of loops as the other post said. In your case though there's altogether a better way to solve this problem and that's using event delegation.

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "div") {
    alert( "Element " + e.target.id );
  }
}
```

If you had jQuery you could do this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "div", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

For more info check out this article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Obviously jQuery and other libs handle this stuff automatically as well.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I don't want to parse the id of the triggering element to get N. Also I tried the code. It seems to need `this.id` be replaced with `e.target.id` to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Event delegation uses way less resources than assigning click events to every div, so I'd still recommend it over the other approach.

Comment: Is this the actual HTML or are you trying to solve a more complex problem?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/ might actually help here if you just want to know the index of the one clicked.

Comment: yeah it's a part of a bigger project, but it was hard to describe so I put up a code snippet to demonstrate exactly the part that I couldn't solve. Thanks for the code and the link.

Answer (score 2):

You could grab the number from the element's `id` attribute:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( "element" + i );
    element.onclick = function () {

        var i = this.id.substr(7);
        alert( "Element " + i );
    }
}​
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3jmP/).

Comment: interesting solution. Though as I said I don't want to parse the id to get the number. This is just an example to demonstrate a bigger "scope problem" from a project.